# Ignoring a field during .NET JSON serialization; similar to [XmlIgnore]?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I have a POCO class that is being sent to the browser as a JSON string in .NET 3.5 sp1.  I am just using the default JSON serialization and I have some fields that I want to ignore.  I want to put an attribute similar to [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore] on them so that they are not serialized.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I use the [ScriptIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) attribute on my model like so:

```
public class Item
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public Item ParentItem { get; set; }
}
```

In this particular scenario I was getting a circular reference error from the Json serializer, so I simply ignored it.  I was [asking a similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269106/how-do-i-prevent-json-serialization-in-asp-net-mvc) when I was turned on to the difference between a Model and ViewModel.

Comment: what if its not POCO but a generated EntityModel, I do not want to edit the generated code, is there a workaround to add ScriptIgnore attribute to the generated entity model.

Comment: @hazimdikenli you might have to utilize partial class for this.

Comment: Don't forget to add a reference to "System.Web.Extensions" for this to work

Comment: This helped me stop my toJson(Model) bringing back some unwanted fields,, but ideally with an API, you will need to make an new Area, with a New Model and controller to avoid cross annotations.. but im too lazy. Thanks +1

Answer (score 27):

```
[ScriptIgnore]
```

is your huckaberry.

Comment: It's actually "Huckle Bearer", but I'll give you a +1 for the effort and movie. :)

Comment: The original answer is correct, he says "huckleberry", not "huckle bearer".  http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Tombstone.html

Comment: ...as in "Huckleberry Finn" - a reference to the quintessential "every man", who instinctively strives to "do the right thing" - a true friend you can always count on...hence "I'm your Huckleberry", meaning "you can count on me".

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the
`[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]` into your text template (.tt) file.

Here a portion of my text template before

```
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
```

Once I inserted the code the line above the `codeStringGenerator` my classes auto generated and looked like this:

```
[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
public virtual ICollection<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
```

I also needed to modify the `UsingDirectives` function to insert `"using System.Web.Script.Serialization;"`

Comment: `ApplyToOverrides` seems to be very important on a virtual property

Answer (score 1):

Set property as internal. Depends on your structure, though. Take into consideration.