# Ignore a field during Java JSON-RPC serialization; [ScriptIgnore]?

Tags: java, json-rpc

I'm getting "JSONRpcClientException: ... circular reference." when serializing my domain objects with JSON. (using jsonrpc1.0).

I'd like to maintain the domain as it is, but need to get JSON-RPC working so I wonder if there is any solution to avoid or skip some fields of a Java class (those *circulars*) of being serialized to JSON as it is [described here for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411577/ignoring-a-field-during-net-json-serialization-similar-to-xmlignore).

Is it posible to use something like ScriptIgnore tags in Java to reach this?

Comment: Looks like json-rpc hasn't been maintained for nearly 4 years. Are you sure you want to start using it again? There are other, more current, JSON frameworks for Java.

Comment: :( I was afraid of hearing that. Could you recommend any framework in particular for JAVA JSON-RPC?